# Displaying version-note on articles

Tags: joomla-3.x, front-end, versions

How can i display a version-note from an article on the front-end – like the date or author tags?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick guide on how to do that:

```
/* First include the path */
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_contenthistory', 'ContenthistoryModel');

/* Now instantiate the model */
$historyModel = JModelLegacy::getInstance('History', 'ContenthistoryModel');

/* Now get the content history of the current article */
$items = $historyModel->getItems();

/* Now get the last item. Note that depending on the ordering, you may need to get the first item */
$lastItem = array_pop($items);

/* Now you can get the latest note */
$latestNote = $lastItem->version_note;
```

Note that I haven't tested the above code, but technically it should work.